# How to access dictionary items in SPD 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I'm trying to iterate over a dictionary in a SP Designer 2013 workflow. I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow-6956bd6bed9f) near the bottom it says

```
If you have a plain collection of string values, the path can look like this ([%Variable: ind%])
```

And as you can see in my setup below that is what I have. (I called my counter `index` instead of `ind` but I don't think that should make the difference.

[image]

Unfortunately when I try and run the workflow it is suspended. The error is

```
Indexing by an integer value is not supported on an instance of 'Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicObject'. at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicItem.get_Item(Int32 index)
```

I've looked at several other tutorials and answers and they all say that this is how you do it. So what is missing? How do I iterate through each item in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I did something similar by first converting the dictionary to a string (Set workflow variable) and then parsing the string in a loop.

The returned string looks like this: `{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}`

You can search the web for a number of examples of parsing delimited text in a workflow loop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't really address that every tutorial on dictionaries say that you can iterate over it and yet it throws an error.

Comment: The tutorials are probably describing working with JSON data received from a web service instead of using the "Build a Dictionary" feature. Thinking about it a bit... note that the returned string from "Build a Dictionary", `{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}`, defines a single object with three properties. Not a string that defines a collection with three objects. `[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"}]`. Loops typically work with collections.